# addEventListener - the function execute before it is called

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I'm learning JavaScript's Event-listener.
This is my code:

```
var x = 0;

document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    x++;
    document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = x ;
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<body>
  <h1>Headline</h1>
  <button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
  <p id="para">Some text</p>
  <script src="JS.js"></script>
</body>
```

The issue is that `myFunction()` is called both when the page is loaded AND when I click on the button. Why is that and how do I fix it?
I tried to put the script in the HTML's head but then it gives me an error because the button element isn't yet loaded.

Comment: document.getElem....MyBtn.addEventListener... **or** onclick="myFunction()"

Comment: You've bound the click event on the same button twice. In HTML and in JS.

Comment: Remove `onclick`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you

```js
var x = 0;

document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    x++;
    document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = x ;
    console.log(x)
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Headline</h1>
  <button id="myBtn">Click</button>
  <p id="para">Some text</p>
</body>
```

Because you're calling function twice when you click for the first time

Comment: Yup, this is it, didn't notice it :P